# Is it possible to create a folder inside the group policy objects folders in Active Directory Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain-controller

By default all active directory GPOs are created inside Group Policy Objects folder in the group policy management. I was wondering if there was a way to make sub folders inside of group policy objects to group by IE settings, Outlook settings, ETC.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, [you cannot create](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/af9841ea-1448-4c5f-bf33-122b27dfb350/group-policy-objects-subfolder?forum=winserverGP) subfolders in Group Policy. I generally create them with an abbreviation of where and what they're for: `US-IE-Trusted Sites Settings` or `US-PA-Mapped Drives` so I can easily find them.

Comment: Thank You! I wish Microsoft had this capability. Your naming scheme will work awesome though.